# GIFs from website run slow on iDevices

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, gif

I have a website that includes a few loading Gifs that spin while certain pages are loading. The spinning is very fluid on desktop web browsers, including safari on mac.

However, when using safari on an iPad or iPhone, or displaying the webpage in a UIWebView, the gifs spin very slow.

Is there something I can do to my GIF, or my iDevices to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIF spinners are evil. Use this: http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/